# String index out of bounds error, cant find the root of the error

Tags: java, string, indexing, bounds, indexoutofboundsexception

When I try to run my program, it gives the following error...

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at Woordzoeker.check(Woordzoeker.java:88)
    at Woordzoeker.main(Woordzoeker.java:8)
```

I understand that the `String` probably went over the boundaries of an array, but I can't seem to understand why. Could someone please assist me to understand the problem.

This is my code...

```
public class Woordzoeker {
    public static String[] words = {"boom","ma","maat","kas","kast","as","boek","boot"};
    public static String[][] grid = {{"b","o","e","k"},{"o","o","z","a"},{"o","j","o","s"},{"m","a","a","t"}};
    public static String[][] gridz = new String[4][4];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int x=0; x < words.length-1; x++){
            System.out.println(words[x] + " --> " + check(words[x],grid));
        } // THIS IS LINE 8
        System.out.println(isCorrectGrid(grid));
        System.out.println(isCorrectWords(words));
        }

public static int[] check(String word, String[][] grid){
    int[] array = new int[3];
    int y = 0;
    for (int rij=0; rij < grid.length; rij++){
        for (int kolom = 0;kolom < grid[rij].length; kolom++){
            for (int x=0; x < words.length - 1; x++)
                if (words[x].charAt(y) == (grid[rij][kolom].charAt(0))){  // THIS IS LINE 88
                    array[0] = rij;
                    array[1] = kolom;  // slaat de begin coordinaten op
            for (y = 0; y < words[x].length() - 1; y++){
                if (words[x].charAt(y) == grid[rij + y][kolom].charAt(0)){
                    array[2] = 1;
                }
                if (words[x].charAt(y) == (grid[rij][kolom + y].charAt(0))){
                    array[2] = 2;
                }
                if (words[x].charAt(y) == (grid[rij + y][kolom + y].charAt(0))){
                    array[2] = 3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.  The indentation is all over the place.  (And please don't blame SO or your IDE. We've heard it all before.)

Comment: I really have not a clue what youre trying to tell me, sorry mate.
My code look a bit messy yes but thats cause no ones has taught me how i should do it yet. as for a SO or IDE. i SO have no IDEa what that means.

Comment: Your best bet for fixing this mess is to step through it in a debugger.  That'll be worlds faster than asking here.

Comment: where have you used your first argument 'word' in your check method?

Comment: @Rdhao, what Stephen is saying is that your code appears to be horribly formatted (i.e. it's not correctly indented), if you don't know what *indenting* is, please search for "indent code" on google - you'll see how it's done.

Comment: @Nim Thanks, ill look it up. i also just looked up SO and IDE, i shouldve known SO. Anyways, thank you.

Comment: For quick finding the issue put break point on java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. will stop the control when this exception raises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should clear y after last for?

```
for (y = 0; y < words[x].length() - 1; y++){
   if (words[x].charAt(y) == grid[rij + y][kolom].charAt(0)){
   array[2] = 1;
   }
   if (words[x].charAt(y) == (grid[rij][kolom + y].charAt(0))){
   array[2] = 2;
   }
   if (words[x].charAt(y) == (grid[rij + y][kolom + y].charAt(0))){
   array[2] = 3;
   }

}
y=0;
```

check it

Comment: This didnt cut it, but after i reset it after every if i stopped getting the error, so thanks =]

Answer (score 1):

You don't reset `y` in the inner loop, when the loop proceeds to the second word, `y` is 3, but `words[x].charAt(y)` (where `x` = 1) doesn't exist - it's out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

the 2nd word in the array **words** is only composed of 2 letters and you are trying to access the 4th letter in that word by the follwing code **words[x].charAt(y)** but y is equal to **3** which is out of bound for the word **ma**

Answer (score 0):

For some **words** the index specified by y does not exist .

```
         if (words[x].charAt(y) == (grid[rij][kolom].charAt(0))) //in this line If the words is "ma" then charAt(y=3) does not exist ,hence the error .
```

Try resetting y properly in the loop to give expected behavior.

You can analyze your program by debugging it to find out such mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

> I really have not a clue what youre trying to tell me, sorry mate. My code look a bit messy yes but thats cause no ones has taught me how i should do it yet. as for a SO or IDE. i SO have no IDEa what that means.

(IDE stands for Interactive Development Environment.  For instance Eclipse, NetBeans, IDEA, etc.
SO stands for Stack Overflow.  I'm referring to the simple wiki language that SO provides for writing and formatting Questions and Answers.)

If you haven't learned / been taught the rules of Java style, you should spend the time to read this document - [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html).  There are other Java style guides too ... take your pick.  One of the key points of good style is to indent the code consistently.

The reason for style conventions is to make it easier to read your own and other peoples' code.  And to avoid the incidence of workmates lobbing stink bombs into your cubicle.

(If you think I'm being tough on you, just wait until you experience your first full-on code review in a workplace environment ... )

Comment: Thanks, i had already googled most of it but youre right about the stule stuff.
my workgroup monitor was actually surprised too we never had the style explained to us.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with one loop into another is that most of the time we forgot to reinicialize the variables that we use to do the loop. I recommend you to after every loop, reinicialize the variables that you may changed, sometimes is a innecesary step but its a good routine...

As Nim says the problem is that `y` is never re-initialized...

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure what the code is for but I see the check method takes in input a word param but it doesn't use it. Pehraps you used words in the place of word?

Answer (score 0):

A debugger makes it clear: Your index `y` has a value of 3 when it's executed on word "ma".  You shouldn't be using that loop value in that scope.

I'm not sure I understand your logic, but it shouldn't take too long.

Your reformatted code would look like this:

```
public class Woordzoeker {
    public static String[] words = {"boom", "ma", "maat", "kas", "kast", "as", "boek", "boot"};
    public static String[][] grid = {{"b", "o", "e", "k"}, {"o", "o", "z", "a"}, {"o", "j", "o", "s"}, {"m", "a", "a", "t"}};
    public static String[][] gridz = new String[4][4];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int x = 0; x < words.length - 1; x++) {
/* --> */
            System.out.println(words[x] + " --> " + check(words[x], grid));
        }
    }

    public static int[] check(String word, String[][] grid) {


        int[] array = new int[3];
        int y = 0;
        for (int rij = 0; rij < grid.length; rij++) {
            for (int kolom = 0; kolom < grid[rij].length; kolom++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < words.length - 1; x++) {
                    /*-->*/
                    if (words[x].charAt(y) == (grid[rij][kolom].charAt(0))) {
                        array[0] = rij;
                        array[1] = kolom;  // slaat de begin coordinaten op
                        for (y = 0; y < words[x].length() - 1; y++) {
                            if (words[x].charAt(y) == grid[rij + y][kolom].charAt(0)) {
                                array[2] = 1;
                            }
                            if (words[x].charAt(y) == (grid[rij][kolom + y].charAt(0))) {
                                array[2] = 2;
                            }
                            if (words[x].charAt(y) == (grid[rij + y][kolom + y].charAt(0))) {
                                array[2] = 3;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```